# Initialize closure in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I know how to initialize a closure that take no arguments, like this:

```
class testClass {
    var myClosure: () -> ()

    init(){
        myClosure = {}
    }
}
```

However, I could not figure out how to initialize closure like this:

```
var myClosure: (Int) -> ()
```

How do I do that?

Comment: What does "initialize closure" mean?

Comment: @matt if you don't initialize all stored properties in class you have warning - you have initialize all stored properties. Therefore, i should initialize closure stored as property in my class.

Comment: Yes, unless you make in an Optional.

Comment: Are you sure it even make sense to default to a do-nothing closure? What's the context here?

Comment: @Alexander class i make initializer for work either with online results or offline. In offline case i dont need that closure, but i force to create it, because it's not optional.

Comment: @Alexander I think we can agree that the entire requirement is nutty. This looks like an x-y question to me.

Comment: " class i make initializer for work either with online results or offline." That sounds like 2 entirely seperate classes, to me.

Comment: @Alexander it is, but i should re-work many of other classes that work with the one i try to modify.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simple example:

```
class TestClass {
    var myClosure: (Int) -> ()
    init(){
        func myFunc(_:Int) {}
        self.myClosure = myFunc
    }
}
```

Or use an anonymous function:

```
class TestClass {
    var myClosure: (Int) -> ()
    init(){
        self.myClosure = {_ in}
    }
}
```

Or you could do the initialization as part if the declaration of `myClosure`:

```
class TestClass {
    var myClosure : (Int) -> () = {_ in}
    init(){
    }
}
```

But if you don't have the value of `myClosure` at initialization time, why not make it an Optional?

```
class TestClass {
    var myClosure: ((Int) -> ())?
    init(){
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please edit your answer so it will be something like: self.myClosure = ... ?

Comment: I did modify legacy code, so i need to create model that act like class i try to make other initializer for. If i make it optional, i would iterate all over my project to provide either force unwrap or safe unwrap of this optional.

Comment: "If i make it optional, i would iterate all over my project to provide either force unwrap or safe unwrap of this optional." Not if it was an implicitly unwrapped Optional. Anyway, if you don't have the real value of `myClosure` at initialization time, you have to deal one way or another with the possibility that the value of `myClosure` is not its real value.

Answer (score 5):

A closure of type `(Int) -> ()` expects one parameter (and Swift will tell you, that the parameter cannot be implicitly ignored).

So if you want to have a closure that takes one parameter, you have to specify this explicitly:

```
let myClosure: (Int) -> () = { parameter in }
```

(if you don't need the parameter, you can replace it with a wildcard to ignore it)

```
let myClosure: (Int) -> () = { _ in }
```

Alternatively, you can use implicit arguments (`$0`, `$1`, etc.), but they only work when you use the parameter somewhere in the closure (e.g. by assigning it to another variable or passing it as a parameter to a function):

```
let myClosure: (Int) -> () = { print($0) }
```

Comment: +1 even though a `let` that is initialised to a closure that takes a parameter and does nothing is not particularly useful :-)

Comment: @Palle  class testClassB {
    var myClosure: (Int) -> ()
    
    init(){
        myClosure: (Int) -> () = { _ in }
    }
} still returning an error.

Comment: Don't specify the type again when assigning a value to `myClosure`. Specifying the type is only necessary when creating the variable. Instead, just assign the closure to the variable: `myClosure = { _ in }`.

Comment: @Palle thank you again, but you better provide code that will compile when i try to put it in init(){} method.