# what is the type of shared？

Tags: arrays, swift

what is the type of shared？  what is the bracket at the end of the code use for？ 
   Thanks!

```
class CallHistories: NSObject {
  private var timer: Timer?
  private var refreshUICallHistories = false
  private var firebase: DatabaseReference?

  static let shared: CallHistories = {
    let instance = CallHistories()
    return instance
  } ()
}
```

Comment: What is **CallHistories**?

Comment: a class of NSObject

Comment: Then no. To be an array it should be of a type between squared brackets like [CallHistories]. It would be less confusing for you if you follow the naming convention of using the singular form in class names: CallHistory

Answer (score 0):

No, shared is just an instance of CallHistories which is lazily initialized.

Comment: Can you please describe "lazily" ? bcz there is no `lazy` keyword !

Comment: You can read more about it here. [Docs](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH14-ID254)

*Stored type properties are lazily initialized on their first access. They are guaranteed to be initialized only once, even when accessed by multiple threads simultaneously, and they do not need to be marked with the lazy modifier.*

Answer (score 0):

The type is `CallHistories`. It's a singleton, a **single** shared instance of the class which is persistent during the life cycle of the app.

The instance is created lazily that means it's created once on the first access of `shared`.

By the way your code is outdated. In Swift 3+ just write (without the closure).

```
static let shared = CallHistories()
```

And you are going to use it with

```
let sharedHistories = CallHistories.shared
```

Answer (score 0):

- If you are asking whether 'shared' is an array? **Then NO**, 
  It's an instance of `CallHistories`
- If you need to make it as array. Then

  ```
  static let shared: [CallHistories] = {
      let arrayInstance = [CallHistories]()
      return arrayInstance    
  } ()
  ```

PS: (I Have not tested this code)

Answer (score 0):

Shared is an object of type `CallHistories`. There are brackets at the end, because variable `shared` is initialized with closure. You can initialize any variable in this way:

```
let myCustomView: UIView = {
    let view = UIView()
    return view
}()
```

More examples here:

[Initialize closure in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50007118/initialize-closure-in-swift)